# YouTube Live (Quick or 'Hangouts on Air') not working

Tags: youtube, google-hangouts, youtube-live, hangouts-on-air

I can't get YouTube Live to work. It's October 2017, and I know Google is making big changes to Hangouts. I get one of a few different errors:

1. Your domain admin has disabled hangouts on air. (No he hasn't. He is me, and I have enabled hangouts. There is no 'Hangouts on air' in G Suite).
2. A 'it's taking too long to connect, please try again' error or just sitting on a preview video with nothing else happening.

Normal Hangouts (group video that is), as in the ones that automatically populate calendar invites, work just fine (or report 'trouble connecting please try again' and then trying again connects them).

I want to be able to broadcast live on YouTube with guests about to join the call (via video). This works just fine on a different legacy Google Apps account. I have mirrored the admin setting exactly, but no luck. It's still broken.

Comment: Full details here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/GYP8naIRXro;context-place=forum/youtube